# Find the sum of the first $50$ terms of the series $a_{n} = -4a_{n-1} + 3$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic-progressions, slope

I'm not sure where to start this without being given some terms.

Find the sum of the first $50$ terms of the series $$a_{n} = -4a_{n-1} + 3$$ I can see that the common difference is $-4$ and the slope intercept is $3$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I suggest manually computing $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$, then forming a hypothesis of the closed form expression for $a_n$, and then proving the hypothesis.  By the way, I am assuming that the first term is $a_1$.  Assuming so, you need to include a manual specification for $a_1$ in your posting.  For example, are we to assume that $a_1 = 3$?

Comment: By the way, there is no *common difference*.  That is, you should not expect that $a_n - a_{(n-1)} = a_{(n+1)} - a_n.$

Comment: @user2661923 I don't know how to start getting the first term? What is $$a_{n-1}$$?

Comment: It seems as though the intended answer will be a function of the unknown value $a_1$, rather than a number.

Comment: It is not a series, it is a *sequence*.

Answer (score 1):

Verify by induction that $$ 
\displaystyle a_{n} =\frac{3}{5} +( -1)^{n}\left(\frac{3}{5} -a_{1}\right) 4^{n-1}, \displaystyle n\geq 1$$

Then $\sum_{i=1}^{50} a_i=\frac 35\times 50+\Big(\frac 35-a_1\Big)\sum_{i=1}^{50}(-1)^i4^{i-1}$

The second term is a G.P.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$a_{n} = -4a_{n-1} + 3$$ Let $a_n=b_n+k$ and replace
$$b_n+k=-4b_n-4k+3\implies b_n=-4b_n-(5k-3)$$ So, if you make $k=\frac 35$, you face a geometric progression.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first few terms obtained by a direct computation: (assume $a$ is the first term $a_1$)
$$a, -4a+3, 16a-9, -64a+39, \cdots, a_n$$
Now, let's write the $n$th partial sum $S_n$:
$$S_n=a+(-4a+3)+(16a-9)+(-64a+39)+\cdots+a_n+0$$
Doing a shift using zero we get
$$S_n=0+a+(-4a+3)+(16a-9)+\cdots+a_{n-1}+a_n$$
Subtracting term by term: (I don't know how to align these in MathJax, so if someone can please do it, very appreciated)
$$0=a+(-5a+3)-4(-5a+3)+16(-5a+3)+\cdots+(-1)^n4^{n-2}-a_n$$
implying
$$a_n=a+(\underbrace{1-4+16-\cdots}_{(n-2)\text{ terms}})(-5a+3)$$
You can proceed from here.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sum of the first $n$ terms is:
$$\begin{align}a_1&=a_1=\qquad \ \ \ \ \color{blue}{(-4)^0a_1}\\
a_2&=-4a_1+3=-4a_1+3\cdot 1=\color{blue}{(-4)^1a_1}+\color{red}{3\cdot \frac{(-4)^1-1}{-4-1}}\\
a_3&=-4a_2+3=(-4)^2a_1+3(-4+1)=\color{blue}{(-4)^2a_1}+\color{red}{3\cdot\frac{(-4)^2-1}{-4-1}}\\
a_4&=-4a_3+3=(-4)^3a_1+3((-4)^2-4+1)=\color{blue}{(-4)^3a_1}+\color{red}{3\cdot \frac{(-4)^3-1}{-4-1}}\\
\vdots \\
a_n&=-4a_{n-1}+3=(-4)^{n-1}a_1+3((-4)^{n-2}+\cdots+(-4)^2-4+1)=\\
&=\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad =\color{blue}{(-4)^{n-1}a_1}+\color{red}{3\cdot \frac{(-4)^{n-1}-1}{-4-1}} \\
\hline
S_n&=\color{blue}{a_1[1-4+(-4)^2+\cdots+(-4)^{n-1}]}+\\
&+\color{red}{3\cdot \left[\frac{(-4)^1-1}{-4-1}+\frac{(-4)^2-1}{-4-1}+\cdots +\frac{(-4)^{n-1}-1}{-4-1}\right]}=\\
&=a_1\cdot \frac{(-4)^n-1}{-4-1}+3\cdot \frac{\frac{(-4)((-4)^{n-1}-1)}{-4-1}-(n-1)}{-5}=\\
&=\frac1{25} \left[(3-5 a_1) (-4)^n + 5 a_1 + 15 n - 3\right].
\end{align}
$$